# Delete row based on value in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works i.e. deletes a row in a worksheet when a specific column has a value of "PAID"

```
Sub RemoveRows()

Dim i As Long
Dim strtest As String

i = 1

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AG1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

strtest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 33).Text
    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 33).Text = "PAID" Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 33).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

However it is very slow on worksheet with 5000 rows.

Any ideas how to make it a lot faster?

Comment: Use a filter perhaps and delete visible cells.

Comment: Use `Application.ScreenUpdating` as well.

Comment: One piece of advise: when browsing through a collection where you might delete entries, always start at the end and go back to the beginning. Otherwise, in case of two subsequent matching criteria, you might miss one.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons which may affect code execution speed including approach / method of coding. See below revised code with comments.

```
Sub RemoveRowsV2()

Dim i As Long
Dim strtest As String
Dim rngDel As Range

i = 1

'\\ Control features which may affect code processing!
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AG1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    '\\ Build a union of all cells to be deleted
    strtest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 33).Value
    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 33).Value = "PAID" Then
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then 
            Set rngDel = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 33)
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 33))
        End If
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop
'\\ Delete them once
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete

'\\ Reset features which may affect code processing!
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```

Alternatively you can use macro recorder to get primary code based on AutoFilter as @BigBen has suggested!

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you can try:

- Add the statement 'Do Events' at a point within the looping. This "DoEvents is an Excel VBA command that temporarily pauses the execution of the macro to refresh the screen and execute any pending events in Excel." For example:

```
   Do
       ' code execution... 

        DoEvents

    Loop Until rowB = "" Or rowB11 = ""
```

- Prior to looping you could add the statement "Application.ScreenUpdating = False". This turns off the refresh flickering you see of the worksheet during processing.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```